# How can I install SQLServer in MAC M1?

Tags: sql-server, macos, docker, containers

I want to run SQL on my MAC M1, I used guidelines according to this website:
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-sql-server-macos

and I used this instruction:

docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

then:

docker run -d --name example_sql_server -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=Strong.Pwd-123' -p 1433:1433 mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

Now my Docker is showing a Container, but it is not active always. When I click on the run button it becomes active for about 5 seconds and then turn off.
Finally, I couldn't have SQL in Azure or another platform because my Container isn't active.
Please help me.....

Comment: Can you try the command `docker logs example_sql_server` and add any error messages to your post, please? You can also see the error messages in Docker Desktop if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I don't know why docker's container is off.

Answer (score 0):

there's no arm64 version of SQL Server2019, you have to get the **Azure SQL Edge for ARM64**.

it's a light version aimed towards embedded systems, so you basically have a SQL2016 version without RS,AS,IS,no sql agent, no in-memory index nor tables, no full parallelism, no column store, no row level security. but it's still  working fine

Comment: I believe columnstore is supported.

Answer (score 0):

I've filed a suggestion on this topic (SQL Server support for Apple's M1 chips) at MS's feedback site.

It can be found here:
https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/949650e5-3248-ec11-a819-0022484bf651